# 'Settings' object has no attribute 'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, djoser

A strange error 'Settings' object has no attribute 'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL', although Djoser settings have this field. the error occurs when trying to reset the password for an activated account. In addition, Djoser does not send an e-mail for activation of the account for some reason, but it does not display any errors.

````py
DJOSER = {
'USER_MODEL': 'users.Users',
'LOGIN_FIELD': 'email',
"PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": '{}/password/reset/{uid}/{token}',
'ACTIVATION_URL': '#/activate/{uid}/{token}',
'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
'SEND_CONFIRM_EMAIL': False,
'USER_AUTHENTICATION_RULES': \['djoser.auth.authentication.UserAuthentication'\],
'SERIALIZERS': {'user_create': 'users.serializers.UserSerializer',}

}```

the error occurs when trying to reset the password for an activated account.
````

Answer (score 0):

`'{}/password/reset/{uid}/{token}',` is invalid.

[Look here / doc](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html)

It should look something like below.

```
'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't make any difference. ``` 'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': '#/password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}'```

Comment: Where is the url you get?